# Bend svg imported object without stretch

Tags: animation, modifiers

I want to bend an object without deforming it in such a way that it gets stretched.

[In this video](https://youtu.be/FqprC4yS6EI) i try to animate the construction of the a paper character (to use it as an instructional video). The selected item is one of tje objects I want to bend. As you know, paper doesn’t stretch, it just bends (or folds or tears). The selected object(s) need to bend, in order to enter the hole of the other paper object.

I looked up ways to bend the object, like simple deform, bend around an object or empty but they don’t seem to work for me (with the current setup at least). Either the objects stretches or deforms in a weird way because of the lack of loop cuts.

I don’t think it’s possible to divide the mesh with loop cuts because it is an imported svg file.

Is there a proper way of bending these objects without them being stretched?

Comment: If there is no edges, the mesh won't be able to bend : You can try to add a Subdivision Surface modifier but set the mode to "simple" so that the geometry boundaries stay the same, but it just gets denser. Use a triangulate modifier before the subdivision if you get weird results. Other solution is to use the knife tool multiple times or knife project tool with a series of orthogonal planes. Another solution is to use the remesh modifier set to voxel

Comment: Although I think just adding an edge where the ears get seperated from the rest would do the trick. Select two vertices and press "J" to add an edge to separate the face into 2 new faces. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbgHT.png